# Ajax header request is sent empty, why?

Tags: json, ajax, header, request

I need some help on a topic in Ajax, my question is, when i send json data via within the browser console it sent very well, BUT when do it from my script it doesn't, please answer as soon as possible.

Comment: not tell your problem by text,we don't know what it's! Approve by working code...

Comment: Thanks @David Jawphan I just solved the problem!